# Magento Error log record file isn't created under `/var/report`

Tags: magento, error-log

The error log record number created isn't found under `var/report` and i cannot access the backend.

```
`Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 148013902355`
```

How can i solve this ?

I cannot read the error it has printed on that particular log number. It's in remove server and showing in backend `mysite.com/admin`.

**Update** : I can see error after (allowing developermode and enabling to display error in root/index.php file)

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);  //and allowing this
//}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);  //commenting this
```

Comment: Check the directory permissions.

Comment: @DeepakMankotia var folder has permission of `0755` and report folder has '0777'

Answer (score 1):

To view the error in detail on browser rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` in Errors folder in magento root directory. Also please check `var/report` writable permission for error file.

Comment: var folder has permission of 0755 and report folder has '0777'. Renaming to 'local.xml` helped tho

Comment: And the new problem is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447764/mage-registry-key-singleton-info-feed-already-exists) after viewing log