# Mage registry key "_singleton/info/feed" already exists

Tags: magento, singleton

Error i encountered while accessing `mysite.com/admin` admin area is

> Mage registry key "_singleton/info/feed" already exists

I couldn't found anything on web relating this except a discussion in a non [english forum](http://www.internetmojster.com/cms/magento-error.html) and i am not being able to access backend.

Comment: try after clear session and cache

Comment: I have encountered this issue while creating one module with the observer and I havent defined observer properly. check your module possibly feed module...

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this regarding @pankaj Comment

As my backend is already blocked with error page, option i have to clear cache and session is :

> To clear the cache, simply delete everything from the /var/cache
> directory and then reload your website in your browser.
>
> To clear all sessions, you can also delete everything from the
> /var/session folder within your Magento installation directory.